# StringReader finding all instances of my search

Tags: c#

I have a column (nvarchar(max)) in my table that contains javascript code.  As you can see in my example I have 2 separate javascript calls per line.

Line 1:

```
(<a href="Javascript:TermDef(1000,'','451')">aaa</a>)<LI>  <a href="Javascript:TermDef(1100,'','26')">bbb</a>
```

Line 2:

```
(<a href="Javascript:TermDef(1200,'','551')">ccc</a>)<LI>  <a href="Javascript:TermDef(1300,'','270')">ddd</a>
```

I have the following StringReader code that is looping through the string, but it only finds the 1st instance.  This code works great if there is only one instance of what I'm searching for per line.

```
using (StringReader rowData = new StringReader(reader[0].ToString()))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = rowData.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        startVal = 0;
        if (line.IndexOf("Javascript:TermDef", startVal) > -1)
        {
            startVal = line.IndexOf("Javascript:TermDef", startVal);
            endVal = line.IndexOf(">", startVal);
            value = line.Substring(startVal, endVal - startVal - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it to find all instances of "JavaScript:TermDef" in my line?

Comment: Loop through using `startVal = endVal` instead of just checking once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding multiple instances is why the start argument exists.  If you update your start value and loop through until no more instances are found, you can find all of them.

```
using (StringReader rowData = new StringReader(reader[0].ToString()))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = rowData.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        startVal = 0;
        while (line.IndexOf("Javascript:TermDef", startVal) > -1)
        {
            startVal = line.IndexOf("Javascript:TermDef", startVal);
            endVal = line.IndexOf(">", startVal);
            value = line.Substring(startVal, endVal - startVal - 1);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            startVal = endVal;
        }
    }
}
```